# Session attributes not getting replicated properly in tomcat 7 clustering

Tags: java, xml, session, tomcat, serialization

I have the following code in `struts2.3` ::

```
SessionEvent se = new SessionEvent();

se.setSessionID(session.getId());

se.setUserID(user.getUserId());

session.setAttribute("SessionEvent", se);**


Map attributes = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();

attributes.put("USER", user);  // user is a serialized object

attributes.put("ID", 0);

ActionContext.getContext.setSession(attributes);

CustomSessionManager cst = new CustomSessionManager();

cst.setUserID(user.getUserId());

cst.setUserMachineIP(req.getRemoteHost());

cst.setUsersessionId(session.getId());

session.setAttribute("boundUnboundUser", cst);


SessionEvent And CustomSessionManager are Serialized Listener classes ::

public class SessionEvent implements HttpSessionBindingListener, Serializable
{

     public void valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent arg0)
     {

     }
     public void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent arg1)
     {
     }
}




public class CustomSessionManager implements HttpSessionBindingListener, Serializable
{

     public void valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent arg0)
     {

     }
     public void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent arg1)
     {
     }
}
```

Now the problem is that at replication time DeltaManager is able to replicate the SessionEvent and CustomSessionManager Object but unable to replcate user object . Now if i change the sequence of code and put the session code for user above Session Event then user object gets replicated but Custom Session Manager does not . Not sure whether this is a problem in my code or there is problem in behavior of Delta Manager in tomcat 7 . I have marked my web application as  also . My Receiver ports of tomcat are also different . I am using sticky session . Following is server.xml configuration for cluster
I have also specified jvmRoute attribute inside Engine tag in server.xml file . I am using mod_proxy_balancer for load balancing

```
  <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
      /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
      /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
  <!--
  <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
  -->
  <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster" 
                     channelSendOptions="8">



         <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">

         <Membership className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService"
         address="228.0.0.4"
         port="45569"
         frequency="500"
         dropTime="3000"/>

          <Sender className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">
         <Transport className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender"/>
         </Sender>

         <Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver"
         address="auto"
         port="4001"
         autoBind="100"
         selectorTimeout="5000"
         maxThreads="6"/>

         <Interceptor  
                                          className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>

         <Interceptor 
                          className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatch15Interceptor"/>

         </Channel>



         <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve" filter=""/>

         <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve"/>

         <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteSessionIDBinderListener"/>

         <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener"/>

</Cluster>

  <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
       via a brute-force attack -->
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
    <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
         resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
         that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
         available for use by the Realm.  -->
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
  </Realm>

        <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" deployXML="true">
    <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
    -->

    <!-- Access log processes all example.
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
         Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

  </Host>
</Engine>
```